# Error occured in NSDictionary EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I have the following code:

```
NSString * client_type = @"client_credentials";

@implementation OauthObject

- (NSDictionary*) getParamsCredintion{

        return [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:client_id, @"client_id", client_secret, @"client_secret", client_type, "@client_credentials", nil];

}
```

When i try to init NSDictionary with `client_type` key I get error:

> NSDictionary EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: What is the ***exact*** error message? You should probably try to use the Objective-C dictionary literals instead anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in *(you have used @ after quotation)*

`client_type, "@client_credentials"`

Change to

`client_type, @"client_credentials"`

```
- (NSDictionary*) getParamsCredintion{

    return [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:client_id, @"client_id", client_secret, @"client_secret", client_type, @"client_credentials", nil]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary cannot store scalar values (like BOOL, NSInteger, etc.), it can store only objects. You may having Numbers or Bools.

```
NSDictionary *qDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]
    initWithObjectsAndKeys:question,@"questionText",
                           [NSNumber numberWithInteger:questionId],@"questionId",
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:userAnswer],@"userAnswer",
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:correctAnswer],@"correctAnswer",
                           nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the meaning of getParamsCredintion? If the compiler has a sense of humour then that is what makes your code crash... Most likely one of client_id, client_secret, client_type is nil or rubbish. Obviously this isn't your real code, right?

Set a breakpoint on the line where the dictionary is created, and examine the values. Recommended is to assign the dictionary to a variable and return that, so you can set a breakpoint there as well and examine the dictionary or log its value. Make your code debugger friendly.